# how to get string values from list of maps in dataweave 2.0?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have input payload coming like this -

[
  {
    "a": ""
  },
  {
    "a": "abc"
  },
  {
    "a": "pqr"
  },
  {
    "a": "xyz"
  }
]
 and desired output is abc,pqr,xyz

I tried following dwl but couldn't succeed. Here is the code snippet

%dw 2.0

### output application/json

query : payload filter ($.a != '') map (
    $.a
)

Can someone please help me with the dataweave ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your desired output is the string "abc,pqr,xyz":

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.a != "") map ($.a) joinBy  ","
```

If you are trying to get the array ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"]:
Your code is fine...

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.a != "") map ($.a)
```

Comment: Thanks. Answer was there with me all the time. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
query: joinBy(payload.a filter $ !="", ',')
```

1. First select all 'a' fields to return new array of just values.
2. Filter the list for "".
3. Use joinBy function to append array values with a comma.